# SwiftData ModelContext from Controller not matching View?

Tags: swift, swift-data

I am converting and existing Boutique + `ObservedObject` controller based app to SwiftData + `Observable`.

I have two `@Model`s, let's say `Model1` and `Model2`. I'd like access to the data stored in the `ModelContainer` in both the `View` and an `@Observable` controller class.

In the controller class, I have the following:

```swift
@Observable final class MyController {
    public var container: ModelContainer {
        let config = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)
        let container = try! ModelContainer(for: Model1.self, Model2.self, configurations: config)
        return container
    }
    
    public var context: ModelContext {
        ModelContext(container)
    }
}
```

In a function that is used in the background, by widgets, by WatchOS apps/complications, I have the following:

```swift
@Observable final class MyController {
    public func update() async {
        let newEntries = try await self.retrieveEntries(between: interval) 
        for newEntry in newEntries {
            context.insert(newEntry)
        }
    }
}
```

In my app, I have:

```swift
@State private var myController: MyController = MyController.shared //singleton

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        iOSMainAppView()
            .environment(myController)
            .modelContainer(myController.container)
    }
}
```

In my `View`, however, the following does not seem to be retrieving anything:

```swift
@Query(sort: \Model1.date, order: .reverse) var model1: [Model1]
```

Is this because its different contexts? Another post had an answer that said all logic should be encapsulated in the `View`, but I need to share the logic between many `View`s, so I think a controller would make sense here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that in the class MyController both `container` and `context` are computed properties which means new instances gets created every time you access any of the properties.

Not only is it a costly operation but it will also mean that your data will most likely be lost because before the context has been saved (which is an asynchronous operation if you use auto save) it will have been replaced by a new one.

So make them stored properties instead

```
@Observable final class MyController {
    public let container: ModelContainer = {
        let config = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)
        let container = try! ModelContainer(for: Model1.self, Model2.self, configurations: config)
        return container
    }()
    
    public var context: ModelContext

    init() {
        self.context = ModelContext(container)
    }
}
```

Or move the creation of the container inside the init as well if you prefer.

Comment: Of course! I feel like an idiot. Thank you for your answer, it worked perfectly. Really appreciate it.